# HTML code is getting send in email instead of rendered view Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have added an action to send email after every post update, in email logs I can see proper view is getting sent, but I don't understand why gmail is showing html code of template instead of rendered view.

Functions.php

```
$email_body = file_get_contents(get_stylesheet_directory(). '/email/template2.php');    
$headers = 'From: Test <support@test.com>';
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html";
$title = wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_title( $post->ID ) );
     if ( get_post_type( $post->ID ) === 'property' ) {
            wp_mail( $emails, $title, $email_body, $headers );
        }
```

html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
  <div style="background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width:100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;
  margin:0;
  padding: 70px 0 70px 0;">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%">
  <tr>
  <td align="center" valign="top"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="template_container" style="
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) !important;
  box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) !important;
  -webkit-border-radius:6px !important;
  border-radius:6px !important;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius:6px !important;
  border-radius:6px !important;">
  <tr>
  <td align="center" valign="top"><!-- Header -->
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="template_header" style="background-color:#075E86;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius:6px !important;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius:6px !important;
  border-top-left-radius:6px !important;
  border-top-right-radius:6px !important;
  border-bottom: 0;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;">
  <tr>
  <td><h1 style="color: #ffffff;
  margin:0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius:6px !important;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius:6px !important;
  border-top-left-radius:6px !important;
  border-top-right-radius:6px !important;
  padding: 28px 24px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  display:block;
  font-family:Arial;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  font-size:30px;
  font-weight:bold;
  border-bottom:0;
  text-align:left;
  line-height: 150%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.5);">
  <a  style="color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;" href="'.site_url().'" target="_blank"> Propery status update </a></h1></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <!-- End Header --></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td align="center" valign="top"><!-- Body -->
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="template_body">
  <tr>
  <td valign="top" style="
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  -webkit-border-radius:6px !important;
  border-radius:6px !important;
  "><!-- Content -->
  <td valign="top"><div style="
  color: #555;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:150%;
  text-align:left;
  ">
  <br/> <br/><center><img src="images/image-5.png" height="60px"><br><br><br>
  Thanks for being a "Submit All Offers" property agent!<br />&nbsp;This email is to notify you that we have recently noticed that you've submitted an offer for property <a href='[post_url]'><b>[title]</b></a>, thereby now the status of the property has been changed to <b>[status]</b>.
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: top;" border="0">
  <tr>
  <br><br><br></td></center>
  <!-- End Body --></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td align="center" valign="top"><!-- Footer -->
  <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="template_footer" style="
  border-top:0;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:6px; border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
  webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:6px; border-bottom-right-radius:6px; overflow:hidden
  ">
  <tr>
  <td valign="top" style="background:#eee;-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.1);"><table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
  <td colspan="2" valign="middle" id="credit" style="
  border:0;
  color: #c1d46b;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:125%;
  text-align:center;
  "><p><a  style="color: #666;text-decoration:none;" href="'[url]'" target="_blank">[site_name]</a></p></td>
  </tr>
  </table></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <!-- End Footer --></td>
  </tr>
  </table></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

In post SMTP logs, I can check proper view is generating, but in gmail inbox, HTML Code is coming in email body, can anyone help?

Comment: Divs are not allowed in emails.  Read this - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ . Each email app reads differently. The more complex email you send more time you will need to fix bugs , rendering etc.